# Ordenar linhas de TXT conforme ordem numérica

Tags: python, python-2.7

Eu necessito inverter todas as colunas do meu arquivo txt, usando python.
Arquivo txt(exemplo):

```
Regra n10 - exemplo
Regra n9 - exemplo
Regra n8 - exemplo
Regra n7 - exemplo
Regra n6 - exemplo
Regra n5 - exemplo
Regra n4 - exemplo
Regra n3 - exemplo
Regra n2 - exemplo
Regra n1 - exemplo
```

Como já dito, preciso inverter, ficando:

```
Regra n1 - exemplo
Regra n2 - exemplo
Regra n3 - exemplo
Regra n4 - exemplo
Regra n5 - exemplo
Regra n6 - exemplo
Regra n7 - exemplo
Regra n8 - exemplo
Regra n9 - exemplo
Regra n10 - exemplo
```

Já há uma ordem numérica, apenas está invertida, apenas necessito mudar a ordem de todas as linhas, inverter a ordem de todas.
Estou usando o **Python 2.7**!

Comment: os arquivos estão exatamente como você está mostrando? 
Você quer aprender e entender como funciona isso programaticamente, ou quer simplesmente que alguém resolva seu problema?

Comment: O arquivo tá de forma bem simular, só necessito inverter todos, porque já há uma ordem numérica, apenas está invertida. Gostaria apenas de uma solução, pois só vou usar dessa vez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se couberem em memória é bem simples. Você lê todas as linhas do arquivo, e depois percorre sobre eles em ordem reversa.

```
arquivo = open("nomearquivo.txt", "r")
conteudo = arquivo.readlines()
arquivo.close()
arquivo_saida = open("novoarquivo.txt","w")
for linha in conteudo[::-1]:
    arquivo_saida.write(linha)
arquivo_saida.close()
```

Comment: Você é um gênio! Muito obrigado!